# How can I get more members in clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am a leader of a clan named Invincible Team,
but I dont get enough members. It has become Level 3 today, but there are only 11-17 members.

Please tell me that how can I get enough members like 30+.
My town hall is 7.

Comment: You can always invite people from global chat, or invite clanless people in your league

Comment: If that is what you were looking for, I can put it in the answer section. Also to add, on SE, you refer to people by doing their name with an at symbol at the start of the comment so: `@JohnSmith Thanks`. Also, remove spaces. Just to keep in mind, as people might not be notified without it

Answer (score 2):

As leader (or co-leader/elder), you have the right to invite anyone into your clan that has a clan castle and is currently in no clan.

As incentives, people like free promotions, usually free elder is best. Doing lots of wars and having high-level players and good troops will also attract players. A serious clan description will also prove that your clan is serious and is a good clan to be in. Higher level clans and high trophy players should also help.